# Show div by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My code is working fine. I just want to make the hidden div visible. It is hidden by default. It show the div when I click on the link.  I need a help to show the div by default. I tried few things but i am  not able to find the right way.

```
    #morelist {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style:none;
        padding-right:50px;
        float:left;
        font:15px/18px'Playfair Display', serif;
    }
    .show {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .show b {
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    .hidden {
        display:none;
        float:left;
        width:400px;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".hidden").hide();
        $(".show b").html("Show");

        $(".show").click(function () {
            if (this.className.indexOf('clicked') != -1) {
                $(".hidden").hide();
                $(this).removeClass('clicked')
                $(this).children("b").html("Show");
            } else {
                $(".hidden").hide();
                $(".show").removeClass('clicked');
                $(".show").children("b").html("Show");
                current = $(this).children("b").attr("class");
                $("#" + current).show();
                $(this).addClass('clicked')
                $(this).children("b").html("Hide");
            }
        });

    });
<ul id="morelist">
    <li class="show"><b class="aform">Show</b> a Form</li>
    <li class="show"><b class="apicture">Show</b> a picture with text</li>
</ul>

    <div id="aform" class="hidden">

    <h3>Enter your login password below:</h3>

        <form id="two" action="..." method="post">
            <fieldset id="personal">
                <label for="login">login :</label>
                <input name="login" id="login" type="text" tabindex="1" />
            </fieldset>
            <p class="buttons">
                <input id="button1" type="submit" value="Send" />
                <input id="button2" type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="apicture" class="hidden">
        <img src="more_and_more/image.jpg" title="" alt="pretty woman portrait" />
            <h3>Pretty woman portrait</h3>


    </div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjnc4/)

Comment: I'd suggest you to read some basic tutos...

Comment: `$(".hidden").show()` instead of `$(".hidden").hide()`?

Comment: If I do $(".hidden").show(); my both div's are visible

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want it to be hidden, don't put "hidden" in the class of the div in question.

If your goal is to only have one of 2 element show at a time, then you can start with the one you want initially hidden to have the hidden class, and then use jQuery's toggleClass("hidden") on the two elements: this will remove hidden from the one that has it (hence, showing it) and add it to the one that doesn't (thus, hiding it).

Comment: @AlienArrays - if the class `hidden` is removed. `$('.hidden').hide()` doesn't do anything & this will work.

Comment: @Krishna correct! But it is true than `$('.hidden').hide()` which OP is using doesn't make sense at all

Answer (score 0):

I think the div that's hidden by default is this one?

```
<div id="apicture" class="hidden">
```

You gave it the default class "hidden" there.

".hidden" is declared as "display: none;" in your CSS code.

If you want it to be displayed by default it needs another display value. Standard is "display: inline;" as far as i know.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways. One of it is to change the css attribute of the element as follows

```
.hidden {
    display:BLOCK;
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}
```

You can either remove it like this

```
.hidden {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}
```

Or you can remove the class of the div you don't want to be hidden.

```
<div id="apicture" class="hidden">
```

will become

```
<div id="apicture">
```

and

```
<div id="aform" class="hidden">
```

should be

```
<div id="aform">
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: When I remove teh class hidden from the one I dont want to be hidden. Then in that case when I click on another link the one was still visible from which I removed the hidden class it wont get hide if i click on other link.. then i see 2dives. I want the one which is visible bydefault should get hide when the other div is visible.

Comment: I can't really understand what's your goal. When the page loads you want to see both forms as visible and the divs text to be "hide this form" "hide other form" ? In general you want to avoid that first 'Show form' click on the div to display it ?